# Data race occurs even if using sync.Mutex in map

Tags: go, concurrency

How can I solve data race bug in this piece of code? I get an error in `processPbxQueueByUniqueID` func on `l.Remove(frontItem)`. Do I need to maybe create another struct that contains sync.Mutex and *list.List and then change `pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor.processes` to `map[string]NewStructWithMutexAndList`?

```
var pbxQueueUnique = newPbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor()
var pbxMutex sync.Mutex

type pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor struct {
    processes map[string]*list.List
}

func newPbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor() *pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor {
    return &pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor{processes: make(map[string]*list.List)}
}

func (q *pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor) Add(uniqueID string, item pbxQueueItem) {
    pbxMutex.Lock()
    defer pbxMutex.Unlock()
    _, ok := q.processes[uniqueID]

    if !ok {
        l := &list.List{}
        l.PushBack(item)
        q.processes[uniqueID] = l
        go processPbxQueueByUniqueID(uniqueID)
        return
    }

    q.processes[uniqueID].PushBack(item)
}

func (q *pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor) Get(uniqueID string) *list.List {
    pbxMutex.Lock()
    defer pbxMutex.Unlock()

    return q.processes[uniqueID]
}

func (q *pbxQueueUniqueIDProcessor) RemoveFromList(uniqueID string, el *list.Element) {
    pbxMutex.Lock()
    defer pbxMutex.Unlock()
    l := q.processes[uniqueID]
    if l == nil {
        return
    }

    l.Remove(el)
}

func processPbxQueueByUniqueID(uniqueID string) {
    l := pbxQueueUnique.Get(uniqueID)
    if l == nil {
        return
    }

    for {
        frontItem := l.Front()
        if frontItem == nil {
            break
        }

        frontValue := frontItem.Value.(pbxQueueItem)
        execAcc(frontValue)
        l.Remove(frontItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: The mutex is only protecting the map, not the values in the map.

Comment: processPbxQueueByUniqueID accesses lists outside of the mutex.  The solution described in the question is one way to fix the problem.   Another option is to lock `pbxMutex` in processPbxQueueByUniqueID.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Does calling `pbxQueueUnique.Get(uniqueID)`  already locks `pbxMutex` or am I completely wrong?

I thought that would be enough.

Comment: `pbxQueueUnique.Get(uniqueID)` unlocks the mutex on return from the function.  Lock the mutex again in `processPbxQueueByUniqueID`